# Errors while upgrade GWT to v2.4

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, ant, compiler-errors

I am trying to upgrade GWT to v2.4. I am facing problems. When Run As -> Ant Built (after upgrade the project), the .xml files are missing (not generated in the project) and the project build successfully, but there is strange behavior which shows errors in the console. I will post the errors that are appearing (some of them).

I am using the following:

- operating system is Windows.
- I make the compiler to be jdk1.7 instead of jre1.5.
- I set these in the Environment Variables: classpath point to C:\Program Files\Documentum\dctm.jar;C:\Documentum\config;%GWT_HOME%;%GWT_HOME%\gwt-user.jar;%GWT_HOME%\gwt-dev.jar;%GWT_HOME%\gwt-servlet.jar;%junit%
- GWT_HOME D:\products\DSS 2012\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37\gwt-2.4.0
- JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05"
- junit %JUNIT_HOME%\junit.jar
- JUNIT_HOME D:\products\DSS 2012\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705

In the eclipse --> Preferences --> Java --> compiler --> Compiler compliance level to 1.7

In the eclipse --> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs --> set it to jdk1.7.0_05

These are some of the errors that are appearing while doing the compiling (the result I got is successfully compiled)

```
[java] Loaded 2283 units from persistent store.
 [java]    Found 2215 cached units.  Used 2215 / 2215 units from cache.
 [java]    Added 0 units to persistent cache.
 [java]    Validating newly compiled units
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/EditorDriver.java'
 [java]          Line 20: The import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 97: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/impl/AbstractSimpleBeanEditorDriver.java'
 [java]          Line 28: Name clash: The method setConstraintViolations(Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>>) of type BaseEditorDriver<T,E> has the same erasure as setConstraintViolations(Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>>) of type EditorDriver<T> but does not override it
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/impl/BaseEditorDriver.java'
 [java]          Line 31: The import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 66: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/impl/SimpleViolation.java'
 [java]          Line 25: The import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 40: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 43: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 44: Missing code implementation in the compiler
 [java]          Line 49: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 49: Missing code implementation in the compiler
 [java]          Line 70: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 72: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 73: ConstraintViolation<?> cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 78: ConstraintViolation<capture#2-of ?> cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 83: ConstraintViolation<capture#3-of ?> cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 92: ConstraintViolation<capture#4-of ?> cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 97: ConstraintViolation<capture#5-of ?> cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 102: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/testing/MockSimpleBeanEditorDriver.java'
 [java]          Line 26: The import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 35: The type MockSimpleBeanEditorDriver<T,E> must implement the inherited abstract method EditorDriver<T>.setConstraintViolations(Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>>)
 [java]          Line 107: Name clash: The method setConstraintViolations(Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>>) of type MockSimpleBeanEditorDriver<T,E> has the same erasure as setConstraintViolations(Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>>) of type EditorDriver<T> but does not override it
 [java]          Line 108: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/AbstractGwtValidatorFactory.java'
 [java]          Line 21: The import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 23: The import javax.validation.TraversableResolver cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 24: The import javax.validation.Validator cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 25: The import javax.validation.ValidatorContext cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 26: The import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 57: ValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 67: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 68: The method create(Class<?>) from the type GWT refers to the missing type ConstraintValidatorFactory
 [java]          Line 68: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 75: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 76: The method create(Class<?>) from the type GWT refers to the missing type TraversableResolver
 [java]          Line 76: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 79: Validator cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 81: The method getConstraintValidatorFactory() from the type AbstractGwtValidatorFactory refers to the missing type ConstraintValidatorFactory
 [java]          Line 82: The method getTraversableResolver() from the type AbstractGwtValidatorFactory refers to the missing type TraversableResolver
 [java]          Line 91: ValidatorContext cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 92: The method create(Class<?>) from the type GWT refers to the missing type ValidatorContext
 [java]          Line 92: ValidatorContext cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/BaseGwtConfiguration.java'
 [java]          Line 23: The import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 25: The import javax.validation.TraversableResolver cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 26: The import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 27: The import javax.validation.spi.BootstrapState cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 40: BootstrapState cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 43: BootstrapState cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 45: BootstrapState cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 53: ValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 55: The method buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationState) from the type GwtValidationProvider refers to the missing type ValidatorFactory
 [java]          Line 59: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 64: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 65: The method create(Class<?>) from the type GWT refers to the missing type ConstraintValidatorFactory
 [java]          Line 65: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 72: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 73: The method create(Class<?>) from the type GWT refers to the missing type TraversableResolver
 [java]          Line 73: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 88: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/BaseMessageInterpolator.java'
 [java]          Line 26: The import javax.validation.metadata cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 41: ConstraintDescriptor cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 44: ConstraintDescriptor cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 45: ConstraintDescriptor<?> cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 49: ConstraintDescriptor cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 50: ConstraintDescriptor<capture#2-of ?> cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 134: The method getConstraintDescriptor() from the type MessageInterpolator.Context refers to the missing type ConstraintDescriptor
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/GwtConstraintValidatorFactory.java'
 [java]          Line 18: The import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 19: The import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 46: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 53: ConstraintValidator cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 55: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/GwtTraversableResolver.java'
 [java]          Line 20: The import javax.validation.Path cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 21: The import javax.validation.Path cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 22: The import javax.validation.TraversableResolver cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 30: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 33: Node cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 34: Path cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 40: Node cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 41: Path cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/GwtValidationProviderResolver.java'
 [java]          Line 24: The import javax.validation.ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 25: The import javax.validation.spi.ValidationProvider cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 35: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 37: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 38: The method createValidationProviderList() from the type GwtValidationProviderResolver refers to the missing type ValidationProvider
 [java]          Line 40: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 41: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 41: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 42: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 42: The method create(Class<?>) from the type GWT refers to the missing type ValidationProvider
 [java]          Line 42: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 47: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 48: Missing code implementation in the compiler
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/GwtValidatorContext.java'
 [java]          Line 21: The import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 23: The import javax.validation.TraversableResolver cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 24: The import javax.validation.Validator cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 25: The import javax.validation.ValidatorContext cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 26: The import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 34: ValidatorContext cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 36: ValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 38: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 38: The method getConstraintValidatorFactory() from the type AbstractGwtValidatorFactory refers to the missing type ConstraintValidatorFactory
 [java]          Line 40: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 40: The method getTraversableResolver() from the type AbstractGwtValidatorFactory refers to the missing type TraversableResolver
 [java]          Line 42: ValidatorContext cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 43: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 45: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 45: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 47: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 52: Validator cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 54: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 55: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 59: ValidatorContext cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 69: ValidatorContext cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 70: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 72: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 72: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 74: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/Validation.java'
 [java]          Line 23: The import javax.validation.ValidationException cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 24: The import javax.validation.ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 25: The import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 26: The import javax.validation.bootstrap cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 27: The import javax.validation.bootstrap cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 28: The import javax.validation.spi.BootstrapState cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 29: The import javax.validation.spi.ValidationProvider cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 93: GenericBootstrap cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 94: BootstrapState cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 96: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 97: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 100: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 100: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 101: The method getDefaultValidationProviderResolver() from the type Validation.GenericBootstrapImpl refers to the missing type ValidationProviderResolver
 [java]          Line 101: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 103: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 107: ValidationException cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 113: ValidationException cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 121: ValidationException cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 128: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 129: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 130: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 130: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 132: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 135: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 136: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 139: GenericBootstrap cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 139: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 140: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 147: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 148: ProviderSpecificBootstrap cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 150: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 166: ValidationException cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 171: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 172: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 172: The method getDefaultValidationProviderResolver() from the type Validation.GenericBootstrapImpl refers to the missing type ValidationProviderResolver
 [java]          Line 175: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 178: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 180: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 182: ValidationException cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 186: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 190: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 190: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 194: ValidationException cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 206: ProviderSpecificBootstrap cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 207: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 208: ValidationProviderResolver cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 227: ValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 228: The method byDefaultProvider() from the type Validation refers to the missing type GenericBootstrap
 [java]          Line 248: GenericBootstrap cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 276: ValidationProvider cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 277: ProviderSpecificBootstrap cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 278: Bound mismatch: The type U is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <U extends ValidationProvider<T>> of the type Validation.ProviderSpecificBootstrapImpl<T,U>
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/constraints/AbstractDecimalMaxValidator.java'
 [java]          Line 20: The import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 21: The import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMax cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 31: ConstraintValidator cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 31: DecimalMax cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 39: DecimalMax cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/constraints/AbstractDecimalMinValidator.java'
 [java]          Line 20: The import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 21: The import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMin cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 30: ConstraintValidator cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 30: DecimalMin cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 34: DecimalMin cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/constraints/AbstractDigitsValidator.java'
 [java]          Line 20: The import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 21: The import javax.validation.constraints.Digits cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 30: ConstraintValidator cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 30: Digits cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 35: Digits cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]       Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/products/DSS%202012/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205021203-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/constraints/AbstractMaxValidator.java'
 [java]          Line 21: The import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 22: The import javax.validation.constraints.Max cannot be resolved
 [java]          Line 29: ConstraintValidator cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 29: Max cannot be resolved to a type
 [java]          Line 33: Max cannot be resolved to a type
```

I don't know what to do. Please any help.

Thanks and regards,

Ali

Comment: Now the project is BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but as I said before, it didn't generate any xml files. Once I deploy and run the application on the server (WebLogic), I got an empty page. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar` and `validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar` to the classpath.

BTW, you don't need `gwt-servlet.jar` in the classpath, as it's a subset of `gwt-user.jar` and `gwt-dev.jar`; and you should set *compiler compliance level* to 1.6, as GWT does not (yet) support Java 7 features (you can use a JDK 7 –except if you use request factory, you'd need to upgrade to GWT 2.5.0-rc1 then– but you have to keep compiler compliance to 1.6, or at least make sure you don't use any Java 7 features –diamond operator, switch on strings, etc.–).

Comment: >First of all, thank you for your reply. 
>1- Do I need any special Java 6 to be used with GWT 2.4? means, do I need SDK 6 or JRE 6 to be installed? 
>2- I found that yesterday and I added these two jars and also gwt-servlet-deps.jar. Then most of the errors disappeared.
My real problem is that before upgrading to GWT 2.4 I was getting .xml files generated, but now I am not getting them. So I don’t how to get them generated. Do I really need these .xml files or not. 
Thank you again and looking for an answer.

Comment: You can use a JDK 7, but stick to the Java 6 syntax. I don't know which XML files you're talking about so it's hard to answer your other question.

Comment: Thank you again for your quick response. As I told you before, when I run the ant script, .xml files are generated to me in war/WEB-INF folder. However, when I upgraded it with the new GWT and JRE 6. They didn't appeared. I will a sample of one of the generated .xml file.

Comment: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cache-entry>
<generated-type-hash class="com.petris.dataservices.client.SearchTemplateService_Proxy" hash="DD6731089BD5EE85A2E64EC8D173BDEF"/>
<generated-type-hash class="com.petris.dataservices.client.SearchResultUpdateService_TypeSerializer" hash="B354A90C9636D48E383E5481635C527C"/>
<generated-type-hash class="com.petris.dataservices.client.SearchResultUpdateService_Proxy" hash="27D4F33FF5B1FFB0BAC02709594F5C9E"/>
 <generated-type-hash class="com.petris.dataservices.client.CommunicatorTransferService_Proxy" hash="58306FDDF608EF4FE39F724C72C22144"/>
'

Comment: <generated-type-hash class="com.petris.dataservices.client.ChildObjectService_TypeSerializer" hash="3938D320486E0A0F361FCEE98392A9BF"/>
 <generated-type-hash class="com.petris.dataservices.client.CommunicatorTransferService_TypeSerializer" hash="F349F9014FF701182B4F0BBDB3768F9D"/>
 <generated-type-hash class="com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializableException_FieldSerializer" hash="1CB9B63ABEC9BE7E663F6C56AA395208"/>

Comment: <generated-type-hash class="com.petris.dataservices.client.SearchTemplateService_TypeSerializer" hash="A99F62E69EF743F151C58B44127E688A"/>
 <generated-type-hash class="com.petris.dataservices.client.GetStagingFiles_Proxy" hash="95D5FFBDFABA26B7180DBECA3F80FC9C"/>
 <generated-type-hash class="com.petris.dataservices.client.LoadUserInfoService_TypeSerializer" hash="B5A4BD69553864D5E8AFDBE59F04B4BB"/>

Comment: untile the end of the .xml file
 <rebind-decision in="com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.FormPanelImpl" out="com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.FormPanelImplSafari"/>
 <rebind-decision in="com.petris.dataservices.client.ChildObjectService" out="com.petris.dataservices.client.ChildObjectService_Proxy"/>
 <rebind-decision in="com.petris.dataservices.client.DataServices" out="com.petris.dataservices.client.DataServices"/>
 <rebind-decision in="com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HTTPRequestImpl" out="com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HTTPRequestImpl"/>
</cache-entry>

Comment: I must say I've never seen such files (and I've been using GWT since 1.4.62). Which version are you upgrading from?

Comment: Anyway, recent versions of GWT do not generate such files, so it's OK if you don't see them. (still strange as I really don't remember ever seeing such things being generated in any version of GWT)

Comment: I have a Question: If I have a project and then I Run As --> Ant Build, Should I get generated .xml files or not?

Comment: It is working fine now. I after I Run As --> Ant Build. I made it ready and put in the server. Then (Thank GOD) it is working fine after all this headache. Thank all for help specially Thomas for your comments and advices.

Comment: Now the project is BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but as I said before, it didn't generate any xml files. Once I deploy and run the application on the server (WebLogic), I got an empty page. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 points:

1. GWT 2.4 is (source) compatible to Java 6 only. So you can't use Java 7 features as they won't compile using the GWT compiler. That's why you should use 1.6 as compliance level.
2. The editor framework of GWT 2.4 requires the validation api (javax.validation) to work correctly. The validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar and validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar should be included in your downloaded GWT distribution. Include them in your classpath.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. > 1- Do I need any special Java 6 to be used with GWT 2.4? means, do I need SDK 6 or JRE 6 to be installed? > 2- I found that yesterday and I added these two jars and also gwt-servlet-deps.jar. Then most of the errors disappeared. > My real problem is that before upgrading to GWT 2.4 I was getting .xml files generated, but now I am not getting them. So I don’t how to get them generated. Do I really need these .xml files or not. Thank you again and looking for an answer.